# Node.js memory leak while piping mongodb gridstore out to web response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks

I'm having trouble with memory leaking when I pipe a large video file from the a MongoDB GridStore object out to the web response.  I'm using Express.  My code (with some things omitted for brevity) is as follows:

```
// "res" is the response for this Express route.
// response header values are set outside this block
// gridstore, etc. are define above the part that counts, here
    gridStore.open(function (err, gs) {

    gs.seek(rangeObj.start, function (err, gs) {
        var current = 0,
            stream = gs.stream(true);

        stream.pipe(res);

        res.on("close", function () {
            console.log("socket closed");
            if(res){
                res.end();
                res = null;
            }
            if(gs){
                gs.close(function(){
                    gs.destroy();
                    gs = null;
                    if(db){
                        db.close(true, function(){
                            db = null;
                            gridStore = null;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        stream.on("end", function () {
            console.log("stream ended");
            if(res){
                res.end();
                res = null;
            }
            if(gs){
                gs.close(function(){
                    gs = null;
                    if(db){
                        db.close(true, function(){
                            db = null;
                            gridStore = null;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        stream.on("close", function(){
            console.log("stream closed");

            if(res){
                res.end();
                res = null;
            }
            if(gs){
                gs.close(function(){
                    gs = null;
                    if(db){
                        db.close(true, function(){
                            db = null;
                            gridStore = null;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying *really* hard to clean up after myself. There's a lot of unnecessary stuff in there from my attempts to hunt this down. Although, maybe I'm missing someting

The video streams fine.  However, the process takes increasing amounts of memory, seemingly without an upper bound.  It also doesn't seem to release the memory even after letting the process idle for hours.

I've tried exposing the garbage collector and running when the response closes (or even on a 5 second interval).  I've also tried executing the node process with the --always-compact flag.  I'm having the same problem in both Windows 7, and Ubuntu 12.04 (node 0.10.4 on both).

Comment: Are you sure that the buffering isn't happening while sending to the client?  I'm wondering if TCP backpressure on the stream ends up making its way all the way through your code.  I suspect not, and that the response data is being buffered somewhere.

Comment: I had that thought, too.  So, I added a file system implementation that does the same thing, and even with 10 simultaneous streams, it never baloons up like that (300-ish MB, tops, compared to 12 GIG and climbing).  Really, the only difference is that in one case I'm piping it from a gridStore, and in the other, I'm piping it from the file system.  I'd expect some more overhead, but there seems to be something wrong with the driver.